# Are the Fisher King in Doctor Who and the 456 in Torchwood: CoE the same monster?

Tags: doctor-who, torchwood

In the Series 9 episode "Before the Flood", the Doctor interacts with the Fisher King. I couldn't help but notice that when the Fisher King spoke its creepy voice, it sounded like the 456 alien from *Torchwood: Children of Earth*.

Are they the same aliens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### No.

The 456, **voiced by [Simon Poland](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0688857/)**, had

> three "heads", connected to one body via three long necks, possibly a conjoined triplet species. It resembled a large, plucked, three-headed swan.

[image: 456]

The Fisher King, **voiced by [Peter Serafinowicz](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0784818/)**, had a single head and resembled a human with a boat over its head:

[image: Fisher King]

These two aliens look very different from each other, and there's no reason to think they're the same species. Plus they were voiced by different actors.

Comment: Also the Fisher King showed no difficulty surviving in normal Earth atmosphere, while the 456 ambassador teleported into a tank filled with "25% nitrosyl chloride, 22% hydrogen chloride, 20% nitrogen, 12% fluorine, 9% hydrogen cyanide, 6% acetone, and 6% phosgene".

Comment: I should mention that my quote is from [this page](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_456).